# jquery object WHEN passed in an INDEX

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

What i know is if I have

```
 <li class="media_item upload" data-actions-permissions="{}" data-info="{}">
 </li>
```

I can use `$(".media_item.upload").data("info")`

But it doesn't work when I have multiple li(s) and I need to get all the `data-info` for each item.

I was hoping something like `$(".media_item.upload")[i].data("info")` would work but it didn't.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question already...?

Comment: Then use the same ? What the difference if earlier example ?

Comment: `.attr("data-info")`

Comment: You're using Angular and mixing it with jquery selectors...why? If this is the case, please don't, and read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: @theblindprophet you should always use `data()` where possible. It's quicker as it saves DOM accesses, and also coerces types for you instead of always returning a string.

Comment: `$(".media_item.upload")[0].data("info")` Why the `[0]`? If you want the first one, use the correct jquery method to do so.

Comment: @KevinB, I want all of them.. so i thought `console.log($("media_item.upload")[i].data("info"));` will work but it doesn't

Comment: yeah [n] gives you a dom node, not a jquery object. dom nodes don't have jquery methods.

Comment: @KevinB, what do you suggest to do then? could you point me to the right direction?

Comment: Yeah, use the appropriate jquery method for getting n element out of y collection. `y.eq(n)`

Comment: omg! thank you @KevinB. Out of curiosity, how am I supposed to know that is the issue when I don't know the cause of the problem?? can't thank you enough. I will update the post and answer my question :)

Comment: well, the `.data` is not a function error should clue you in that you're trying to call a method that doesn't exist. at that point you should investigate *why* the method doesn't exist, and compare it to situations where it *does* exist.

Comment: I will try to remember this lesson. THANK YOU @KevinB

Answer (score 0):

Use the [index-related selectors](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) jquery method.

Didn't this method exist until @KevinB pointed it out. Another lesson though: I shouldn't keep digging on the internet to see how I can make it work but to investigate *why* it doesn't work. **Investigating the situation** is way more important.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function () {    
    alert($(".media_item.upload").attr("data-info"));    
});
```

Comment: I don't get it.. Why can't I pass it an index to get the item i want

Comment: Do not mix .attr() and .data(). Once using .data(), the two will not be kept in sync.